# How can i filter out mimetype JSON only from no of files in python

Tags: python, json, mime-types

I am writing python script to take one by one file from dir and get it mimetype if it's mimetype is not JSON then i want to ignore it. See below part of my script

```
for filepath in files:
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

    mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath, strict=False) //here i want to filter out only JSON file and ignore other one

    version = "0"
    checksum = "0"
    fileext = os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower()     
    # get raw file data
    with open(filepath, "rb") as fr:
        filedata = fr.read()

    oldfilesize = len(filedata)
```

See my comment in above code.. Any resolution???

Comment: You can't really "get the mimetype" of a file, because this isn't metadata that the system maintains.  You can try to identify JSON documents by file extension (look for `.json`), but it's difficult to identify a JSON file by inspection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
for filepath in files:
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

    mimetype = mimetypes.guess_type(filepath, strict=False)
    if mimetype != ('application/json', None):
    with open(filepath) as f:
        try:
            json.load(f)
        except ValueError:
            # It's not json
            continue
    # do stuff
```

but this could be inefficient if there are lots of files, and/or they are large.

Answer (score 1):

Well, `mimetypes` won't help because the mime type `application/json` for `.json` files is *not* inherent to the file metadata. Rather *you* use it to to provide file type info to whoever is going to to handle it, e.g `Content-Type: application/json` in the HTTP response header tells the client that it is JSON.

Anyway, the solution might be as follows,

```
import json
with open("filename", "rt") as f:
    try:
        d = json.load(f)  # no need to name it if you are just checking
    except JSONDecodeError:
        # handle it or just pass
    else:
        # Got a json file, do whatever
```